# Is there anway to fnd out of list item dragged by mouse or by button click

Tags: jquery

I have a two asp.net bulleted lists, and I am using jQuery sortable on them to move items arround.

Now user can click on a checkbox, checkbox will re-arrange items in lists by some logic it's getting from web services.

But when user moves around items, i want to uncheck checkbox, but we also have a update event on lists.

### What I actually want is to figure out when documents are moved by click event and when a user dragged them on to one or another list

In other words, I want to uncheck box, if user drags documents himself, but leave checkbox if checkbox's click event moves documents.

### Edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".someListsClass").sortable({
        connectWith: ".someListsClass",
        cursor: "default",
        update: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function () { ResetFruitsNow(); }, 100);
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    $(".someListsClass").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("[id$=checkBox123]").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: have a look at jquery droppable https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ in particular events.

Comment: I added dropable with drop function, but nothing changed..

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle? a question without any code or effort usually gets no attention.

Comment: @JFit, I just added my code in there, was doing it already ;)

Comment: a jsfiddle would be perfect. Can you do one real quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `$("[id$=checkBox123]").prop('checked', false);` to the `start` event.

Like this:

```
$(".someListsClass").sortable({
        connectWith: ".someListsClass",
        cursor: "default",
        update: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function () { ResetFruitsNow(); }, 100);
        },
        start: function(event, ui){
            $("[id$=checkBox123]").prop('checked', false);
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```